# CheckedTextView set to checked oncreate in listview?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a shoppinglist, where the CheckedTextView is checked if you have already picked your item previously ie the item has a boolean set to true if picked.

I have overriden the getview method to change the CheckedTextView text with setText() and that works but setting the setChecked(true) method in CheckedTextView doesnt not make it checked.

I know that I am not recycling any views in getview(), that will be a later project in the project, right know I need to see a green checkmark =)

Any thoughts? please help.

my xml files:

test.xml

```
 <CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark" 
    android:paddingLeft="5dip" 
    android:paddingRight="50dip" 
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:tag="text1"
    android:text="testtestetstt"
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

listfippel.java

```
package nu.listfippel.mitt;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.style.StrikethroughSpan;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class listfippel extends ListActivity {

    //ArrayList<Ingred> ing; 
    Ingred i1 = new Ingred("banan", 2, 1, true);
    Ingred i2 = new Ingred("äpple", 3, 1, false);
    Ingred i3 = new Ingred("päron", 3, 1, true);
    Ingred i4 = new Ingred("gröt", 3, 1, false);
    Ingred i5 = new Ingred("bröd", 3, 1, false);
    Ingred i6 = new Ingred("kyckling", 3, 1, false);
    Ingred i7 = new Ingred("röd paprika", 3, 1, false);
    Ingred i8 = new Ingred("tårta", 3, 1, false);
    Ingred i9 = new Ingred("bappelsin", 3, 1, false);
    Ingred i10 = new Ingred("gurka", 3, 1, true);
    CheckedTextView ctv;
    Ingred[] ingarray = { i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10 };


    Ingadapter adapter;
    Ingred temp;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);


        ArrayList<Ingred> ing = new ArrayList<Ingred>(Arrays.asList(ingarray));

        adapter = new Ingadapter(this, R.layout.test, ing);
        //adapter = new IngArrayAdapter(ing);

        OnItemClickListener il = new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int index,
                    long arg3) {

                temp = (Ingred)parent.getItemAtPosition(index);


                if (temp.getCheck()){  
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Du avmarkerade nyss den\nklarmarkerade varan " + parent.getItemAtPosition(index).toString(), 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                }

                if (!temp.getCheck()){
                    temp.setCheck(true);

                    //ctv.setChecked(true);
                }
                else {
                    temp.setCheck(false);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };


        setListAdapter(adapter);
        //setTitleColor(Color.RED);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(il);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(2);



    }
    class Ingadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ingred>{

        public Ingadapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<Ingred> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
            row.setTag(R.id.text1, row.findViewById(R.id.text1));

            CheckedTextView ctv =(CheckedTextView)row.getTag(R.id.text1);

            Ingred temp = (Ingred)((AdapterView<?>) parent).getItemAtPosition(position);

            if(temp.getCheck()){
                ctv.setChecked(true);   
            }

            ctv.setText(temp.toString());

            return (row);
        } 

    }

    }
```

Ingred.java

```
package nu.listfippel.mitt;

public class Ingred {

    private String namn;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int volym;
    private double antal;
    private boolean check = false; 
    private String retstring;

    public Ingred(String namn, double antal, int volym, boolean check){
        this.namn = namn;
        this.antal = antal;
        this.volym = volym;
        this.check = check;
    }

    public String toString(){

        if (!this.check){
        retstring = namn + " \n(" + antal + " behövs)";
        }
        else {
            retstring = namn;
        }
        return retstring;
    }

    public boolean getCheck(){
        return this.check;
    }

    public void setCheck(boolean check){
        this.check = check;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are going to use `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`, you need to use the `setSelection()` method on `ListView` to indicate which get checked, not handle that yourself during row binding.

Comment: I commented out the getListView().setChoiceMode(2) and now it works, dont know why but I exscuse myself with being a total noob =)
Feels like it is not a solid code on my part, just hoping it will hold together in the long run, thanks for the tip =)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post: [Android ListView CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE, how to set checked index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146182/android-listview-choice-mode-multiple-how-to-set-checked-index)
It sais that the method setItemChecked of ListView should be used to set the preselection.