# Android ListView CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE, how to set checked index?

Tags: android, listview, checked

I'm using the cool feature of the ListView to show a checkbox next to the item in the ListView. 
I bind my list to an array of strings.
The onClick and onSelectedItem listeners get called fine, in this way I know the index of the "string" checked (or unchecked).

I'm storing all the checked strings into preferences (as a comma-concatenated-string), and everytime the activity becomes visible I would like to set the checked items back in the listview.

Is there a way of doing it? or the CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE doesn't allow to set the checked items?

note: I'm not using a custom view, since what I want to display is just a string and a checkbox. I've tried setSelection(index) but it should set the onlyone selected (highlighted) row.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,names);
m_playlists_list.setAdapter(adapter);
m_playlists_list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the [setItemChecked](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29) method of `ListView`

> Sets the checked state of the specified position. The result is only valid if the choice mode has been set to `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` or `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`.

Comment: thanks mate, I can't believe I've missed it! 

I would just add to call this method after list.setAdapter(adapter);