# setItemChecked() not working

Tags: android

```
  String[] mListContent={"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wedneday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
  setListAdapter( new AlarmDaysAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, mListContent));
  ListView listView = getListView();
  listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);      
  for(ii=0; ii<values.size(); ii++)
  {
      listView.setItemChecked(values.get(ii),true);
      Log.i(" values: " + values.get(ii)," ");
  }
```

I want to check some list items while displaying the `Listview`. 
The Log.i prints the perfect values present in `values.get(ii)` that is the positions which I wanted to be checked by default. How can I achieve it?

Comment: it has positions of the listview which should be checked or selected by default

Comment: what's AlarmDaysAdapter ?

Comment: public class AlarmDaysAdapter extends ArrayAdapter  {
    String[] days;    List<String>listDays;    
    TasksDataSource datasource; 
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public AlarmDaysAdapter(Context context, int layout, String[] mListContent) {
     super(context, layout, mListContent);
     listDays = Arrays.asList(mListContent);
 }
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      return view;
    }

Comment: I don't see the point of AlarmDaysAdapter. why not use a plain ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: yes.. I did have a plain array adapter. but included AlarmDaysAdapter so it may be used to check the individual rows!!

Comment: still don't see. it is the listview that handles the checked states

Comment: ok. by using arrayadapter how can I check the row by default?

Comment: i'd say just the same way you are doing. see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146182/android-listview-choice-mode-multiple-how-to-set-checked-index